# How to get RingCentral Call Queue Members Availability?

Tags: ringcentral, call-queue

How can I get the Call Queue availability for queue members per queue which is shown in the Online Account Portal? I specifically want the `Available`, `Busy` and `Unavailable` statuses shown in the UI under "Members Availability" per queue.

I've found a few Call Queue APIs that can list queues and queue members but they provide member availability like the UI.

Call Queue APIs:

- [Get Call Queues API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Account-Provisioning-listCallQueues)
- [Get Call Queue Members API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Account-Provisioning-listCallQueueMembers)

The image below is from the [article on Call Queue - User Availability and Call Handling](https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/10847-Call-Queue-User-Availability-Call-Handling-RingCentral?language=en_US)

[image: RingCentral Call Queue Member Availability]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is on the right track. Once the list of queue members is available, you can query each user for his or her queue availability.

> **Note:** A user's queue availability as presented below is the same for all queues they are present on so to do a presentation by queue, this information needs to be combined with their queue membership list. This can be retrieved from the queue or user perspective:
>
> - [Call Queue Members](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Account-Provisioning-listCallQueueMembers)
> - [User's Queue List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523000/how-can-i-get-a-users-call-queue-department)
>
> To manage individual queue availability, add/remove the user from the queues of interest which can be done using the [Edit Call Queue Members API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Account-Provisioning-assignCallQueueMembers).

For both steps query the Get User Status API. An example is provided below.

Get User Status API:

- https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Presence-getPresenceStatus

An example request and response looks like the following:

Request:

```
GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/presence
```

Response:

```
HTTP 200 OK

{
  "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/403228676008/extension/403228676008/presence",
   "extension":    {
      "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/403228676008/extension/403228676008",
      "id": 403228676008,
      "extensionNumber": "101"
   },
   "presenceStatus": "Available",
   "telephonyStatus": "NoCall",
   "userStatus": "Available",
   "dndStatus": "TakeAllCalls",
   "allowSeeMyPresence": true,
   "ringOnMonitoredCall": false,
   "pickUpCallsOnHold": true
}
```

Use the following to get the user's queue availability:

**1) User Queue Setting**

The user's Do Not Disturb `dndStatus` property is used for indicating whether the user is accepting or not accepting calls, including for call queues. The user can set their `dndStatus` to be one of the four following values where "Department" is another name for Call Queue:

- `DoNotAcceptAnyCalls`
- `DoNotAcceptDepartmentCalls`
- `TakeAllCalls`
- `TakeDepartmentCallsOnly`

This can roughly be mapped to:

- Unavailable for Queue Calls: `DoNotAcceptAnyCalls` or `DoNotAcceptDepartmentCalls`
- Available for Queue Calls: `TakeAllCalls` or `TakeDepartmentCallsOnly`

**2) User Overall Availability**

The next step is to check the `presenceStatus` property which is an enumerated string with the following values: `Offline`, `Busy`, `Available`. `Offline` maps to `Unavailable` in the UI. This is an overall availability for both personal calls and queue calls.

**3) Queue Member Availability**

To create the queue member availability, combine the two properties above like the following pseudocode.

I added an extra "Available" condition below which is strictly not needed, but useful for explanation:

```
member_availability = 
  user.dndStatus == "DoNotAcceptAnyCalls"        ? "Unavailable" :
  user.dndStatus == "DoNotAcceptDepartmentCalls" ? "Unavailable" :
  user.presenceStatus == "Offline"               ? "Unavailable" :
  user.presenceStatus == "Busy"                  ? "Busy" :
  user.presenceStatus == "Available"             ? "Available" : "Available"
```

This gives the user's availability for all queues they are on so this needs to be mapped to either a queue members list or the user's list of queues.

- [List Call Queue Members API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Account-Provisioning-listCallQueueMembers)
- [User Info API's `departments` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523000/how-can-i-get-a-users-call-queue-department)

**Example Code**

Here's some Ruby wrapper code I wrote to make it easier to update the user's queue status here:

[RingCentral Ruby SDK `extension_presence.rb`](https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/ringcentral_sdk/rest/extension_presence.rb)